# Get current page title using JSOM

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I'm working on SharePoint Hosted App using JSOM. I need to get the title of current page (i.e. the host page) where my client web part is added. I am aware that in SharePoint 2013 Online, host page and app page are in different domain, hence it is not possible to get the page title using JavaScript.
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Get-the-563f2a3d

Comment: @dcc The link posted by you gives me web title, but my requirement is to get current page title from host site.